# Weighted Graph Shortest Path Design C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I'm having trouble coming up with a plan for a project assigned in a C++ Data Structures course. I'm not asking for written code, but a plan of attack. Basically I'm having a hard time thinking this through.

How would you go about constructing a weighted graph from this weighted non-directed [map](http://cs.saddleback.edu/jlebowitz/CS1D/Assignments/Stadium-NonDirected.jpg) with the intention of being able to find the shortest path from a set vertex (Angel's Stadium) to:

1. All major league stadiums
2. All national league stadiums
3. All American league stadiums

I also have to allow a user to plan their dream vacation by selecting Stadiums they want to visit.

The program only needs to print the number of stadiums visited and the total distance traveled in each case.

My first thought is to have methods for each of the four cases. I'm not even sure how I should go about returning the number of stadiums visited and distance. Is using a struct optimal when you need to return two values?

Let alone which algorithm to use for shortest path. I have an implementation of Dijkstra's from a previous assignment. Some others in my class are using a minimal spanning tree.

It would make more sense to have one function for the shortest path that takes in a list of the stadiums to visit but I don't know how I would structure the adjacency matrix.

I'm making an input file to read in the adjacency matrix formated like so (edge, weight):

```
0 1 340
0 2 110
```

Is this the optimal structure for this case? I'm not sure how to differentiate between major league, national, and American. Are separate input files necessary? Or is there a better way of organizing this?

Here's the full assignment if you are interested: [[word document]](http://cs.saddleback.edu/jlebowitz/CS1D/Assignments/CS1D%20Spring%202014%20Project.docx)

Comment: (1) You list 3 criteria here (major, national, American), but the image you link to only has 2 categories (AL, NL).  (2) Finding a shortest path that visits a set of vertices in no particular order is similar to the Traveling Salesman Problem; the only differences are that you don't need a final flight to get back to your starting point, and you only need to visit a subset of the vertices (rather than all of them).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. (1) confused me until just now as well, American and National make up the Major League, so the Major League trip will visit every vertex. (2) This is a community college course and the professor didn't actually teach us about the traveling salesman problem bedsides telling us that it exists and it was out of the scope of this class. That's why this is confusing me.

Comment: You're welcome.  Regarding the TSP, I'm afraid I don't have time to read the entire assignment, but based on your SO question, I still think it will be NP-hard (like the TSP).

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement different instances of TSP (without the final hop) with the stadiums in the tour chosen according to the criteria specified in the question.

For instance,

1. Design a trip to all the major league stadiums with the shortest path starting at a stadium in California.  Print the number of stadiums visited and the total distance travelled.

minCost = inf

for (stadium in CaliforniaStadiums )

minCost = min(minCost, TSP (stadium, MLStadiums))

Hope that helps.

Rudra